# How can I get my Update button to Edit the values in my datagrid (C# wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a wpf C# program that allows a user to add,update and delete their module details to a datagrid. I got the add and delete function to work but I can't seem to get the update button to work. My program isn't required to save the data onto a database, the data exist as long as the program run. ANY TIPS ARE APPRECIATED!

I tried updating my column "last attended" with  my DateAttend {get;set;} which is bound to my datagrid on my mainwindow and my updateModulePage.cs and I set a function to refresh my grid but nothing changes. Most places I've searched for for a solution deal with winForms instead of WPF.

Mainwindow.xaml datagrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="moduleGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="700" Height="322" Margin="0,50,0,0" IsReadOnly="False" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Module Code" x:Name="module_code" Binding="{Binding Code}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" x:Name="module_name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="No. of Credits" x:Name="module_credits" Binding="{Binding creditNumber}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hours Per Week" x:Name="class_hours" Binding="{Binding classHours}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="No. of Weeks" x:Name="week_number" Binding="{Binding weeks}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Date" x:Name="start_date" Binding="{Binding startDate}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Self Study Hours" Binding="{Binding studyHours}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Attended" Binding="{Binding DateAttend}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

updateButton on mainwindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void updateModuleButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Creates an instance of the updateModule window so that the app can update the selected row
            updateModule update = new updateModule();
            
           
            update.ShowDialog();
            if (moduleGrid.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                moduleGrid.SelectedItems[1] = update.modName.Text;
                moduleGrid.SelectedItems[7] = update.attendDate.Text;
            }

            moduleGrid.Items.Refresh();





        }
```

updateModule.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class updateModule : Window
    {
        

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string HoursAttend { get; set; }

        public string DateAttend { get; set; }
        public updateModule()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
        }
        

        

        private void submitButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow main = new MainWindow();

            DateAttend = attendDate.Text;
            
            
            
            Close();
        }

       
    }
```

Comment: How and where do you set the `ItemsSouce` of `moduleGrid`?